# listindex out of range for simple for-loop (dice probability)

Tags: python, list, dice

I'm new to programming so I fail to understand why this part of my code is not working. 
n = 30 when it should equal n = 35. So the error is that "list index out of range" although I've set a range and count6.
Why? And how do I solve this?

When this part of the code runs alone it does not hold any problems. But when It runs with the rest of my code it has "list index out of bounds" error... 
This is the only part of my full code that raises any errors

```
count6 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
freq = 10
dice = random.randrange(1,7)

print('\nProbability for 6 dices:')
for n in range(5, 36):
   percentage_6 = (count6[n - 5] / freq) * 100
   procent_6 = str(percentage_6)
   print('this is n:', n)
   print(n + 1, ':', procent_6, '%')
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce an index error, There is a name error (because `freq` is undefined), but if that is fixed, the code runs fine.

Comment: I see you fixed the name error, but the new code still doesn't produce any errors (so long as `import random` is added).

Comment: It's weird because this part of the code alone does not have problems when it's alone. When it is with my full code it raises errors? This is the only part of my full code that holds problems.

Comment: This is why you should always post a [mcve].

Comment: my bad, you're right. I'll change it

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not create an out of index error so I'm thinking you used count6[n] somewhere in your code.
You access the values of a list using an index not the value itself.

```
count6 =[6, 7, 8, 9, ...  35, 36]
#index   0  1  2  3  ...  29  30
```

so when your n reaches the value of  `count6[31]` you're trying to find the 32nd element of the list (because index start from 0) which does not exist, as the list only has 31 elements(the element with index 0 is the first element)  as shown above.

Even if that's not the case instead of looping using index if possible you should take the more pythonic option and use.

```
for i in count6:
    percentage_6 = (i / freq) * 100
    ...
```

or you can simply use

```
for i in range(6, 37):
    percentage_6 = (i / freq) * 100
    ...
```

if you have to use a list like that I would suggesting using a list comprehension.

```
count6 = [number for number in range(6, 37)]
```

Comment: My guess is that the OP's real code overwrites/modifies `count6` at some point before the for-loop is executed. That would explain why the code in the question runs without error (i.e. because `count6` is re-initialised).

Answer (score 0):

The list contained only 31 numbers, you can choose from 0 to 30:
should be:

```
for n in range(0, 30):
```

or (nicer):

```
for n in range(0, len(count6)):
```

those numbers are the index, not the value himself.

Comment: But: `len(list(range(5, 36))) == 31`.

Comment: those two statements are not equivalent as @ekhumoro pointed out and if OP is using that he should drop the `-5` from `count6[n-5]`

Comment: Yes, and more to the point: the OP's range clearly already works correctly. So changing how `n` is generated won't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The error was when I called count6 later in the code and stopped at rolled6.count(30) (rolled6 is my list for the rolled sum for 6 dices)

```
count6 = [rolled6.count(6), rolled6.count(7), rolled6.count(8), rolled6.count(9), rolled6.count(10), rolled6.count(11),
          rolled6.count(12), rolled6.count(13), rolled6.count(14), rolled6.count(15), rolled6.count(16),
          rolled6.count(17), rolled6.count(18), rolled6.count(19), rolled6.count(20), rolled6.count(21),
          rolled6.count(22), rolled6.count(23), rolled6.count(24), rolled6.count(25), rolled6.count(26),
          rolled6.count(27), rolled6.count(28), rolled6.count(29), rolled6.count(30),]
```

I changed it so that it contains 31,32...36 too

```
count6 = [rolled6.count(6), rolled6.count(7), rolled6.count(8), rolled6.count(9), rolled6.count(10), rolled6.count(11),
          rolled6.count(12), rolled6.count(13), rolled6.count(14), rolled6.count(15), rolled6.count(16),
          rolled6.count(17), rolled6.count(18), rolled6.count(19), rolled6.count(20), rolled6.count(21),
          rolled6.count(22), rolled6.count(23), rolled6.count(24), rolled6.count(25), rolled6.count(26),
          rolled6.count(27), rolled6.count(28), rolled6.count(29), rolled6.count(30), rolled6.count(31), rolled6.count(32), rolled6.count(33), rolled6.count(34), rolled6.count(35), rolled6.count(36)]
```